# Sql Server Concurrency and Unique Constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, entity-framework, concurrency

I have a table as below

```
AssetResource
--
AssetResourceId
AssetId
ResourceNumber
ResourceType
TrackNumber
ChapterNumber
```

I have set Unique Constraint on (AssetId,ResourceNumber, ResourceType).
Resource number should be an unique sequence number for each AssetId and ResourceType

This table is being updated by multiple processes (same code base) concurrently. Or rows are added for same AssetId and ResourceType concurrently.

I always get Unique Key Constraint exception on ResourceNumber. 
So what I did was , when a process add/update a row , I randomly create a large resource number (expecting the random number would be unique) as below

```
 var randomResourceNumber = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks).Next(1000, 100000);
```

But I still got the unique constraint exception. So I decided to let my service to keep trying  till a unique random number is generated. And I created another service (single threaded) to validate the resource number and update the table with proper sequence number.

However while this table is being updated by the new service , there are chances for the table to be updated by the original multi threaded processes with random resource number. So I am running into a circle and things got really messy.

Is there a simple way of fixing this issue?

-Alan-

Comment: If two processes are running at exactly the same time, you're forcing both of them to initialize a `Random` with identical seed values and so both of them will generate the *same* random numbers.

Comment: Will you consider to use a auto increment for those keys instead of handling manually?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, is there a way to create a truly random number?

Comment: @Alex no we cant do that , because resource number is based on some logic

Comment: Any formula for this field?

Comment: @Alex, the resource number is based on the chapternumber (updated the question ) and track number i.e. chapter = 1, Track =1 , resourcenumber = 1 and etc.. and resource number always need to be recalculated everytime a row is added or updated

Comment: About random number you can initialize one random numbers (1 static `new Random()`) generator and use it for all of the application threads. About your problem did you evaluate pessimistic concurrency?